# JavaScript if statement doesn't return true when it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have an input panel:

```
<div id="user_input">...</div>
```

I have a button:

```
<input type="button" id="panel_button">...</button>
```

I have a selector:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.querySelector(id);
}
```

I have an event handler:

```
var button_panel = $('#panel_button');
button_panel.addEventListener('click', fadeUserInputPanel, false);
```

And finally I have 3 functions for fading in and out the input panel:

```
var user_input_panel = $('#user_input');
user_input_panel.style.opacity = 1;

function fadeUserInputPanel()
{
    if(user_input_panel.style.opacity == 1)
    {
        fade_out();
    } 
    else if(user_input_panel.style.opacity == 0)
    {
        fade_in();
    }
}

function fade_out() 
{
    if(user_input_panel.style.opacity > 0) 
    {
        user_input_panel.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        setTimeout(fade_out, 50);
    }
}

function fade_in() 
{
    if(user_input_panel.style.opacity < 1) 
    {
        user_input_panel.style.opacity += 0.1;
        setTimeout(fade_in, 50);
    }
}
```

*The problem is the following:*

When I load up the page, the input panel can be seen - since its opacity's value is 1.

Then I click on the *panel_button*, which starts to make the input panel fade out. It works just perfectly fine, so the opacity goes straight to 0 and the panel slowly disappears.

*But* when I click on the *panel_button* again, it starts to make the input panel fade in, however it stops when the input panel's opacity is 0.1, and it does not go any further.

But according to the 'fade_in()' function - if the opacity is less than 1 - it should continue fading the panel in. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: A demo in fiddle would be more helpful. jsfiddle.net

Comment: Note that `element.style.opacity` is actually a string, not a number.

Comment: @Alnitak But that will be coerced to number when performing a comparison. Isn't it?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy for comparisons yes, but not for `+=`

Comment: Also note that what you're calling `id` in your `$` function is not an ID. It's a *selector*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply parseFloat on the opacity and it should be fixed.

```
function fade_in() 
{
    if(user_input_panel.style.opacity < 1) 
    {
        user_input_panel.style.opacity = parseFloat(user_input_panel.style.opacity) + 0.1;
        console.log(user_input_panel.style.opacity);
        setTimeout(fade_in, 50);
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/bryanray/1c9oo5k5/

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `style.opacity` is not a number, but a string.

```
> document.body.style.opacity = 0
0
> document.body.style.opacity 
"0"
> document.body.style.opacity += 0.1 
"00.1"
> document.body.style.opacity += 0.1 
"0.10.1"
> document.body.style.opacity += 0.1 
"0.10.1"
```

The subtraction for `fade_out()` works OK, but only because the `-=` operator doesn't have concatenation semantics and will always coerce the arguments to be numbers.

To fix, manually coerce the opacity to a number:

```
function fade_in() {
    var opacity = +user_input_panel.style.opacity;
    if (opacity < 1) {
        user_input_panel.style.opacity = opacity + 0.1;
        setTimeout(fade_in, 50);
    }
}
```